# capistrano 3 : cap aborted! Don't know how to build task 'deploy:update'

Tags: node.js, capistrano3

I am trying to deploy a node.js application onto my remote server
running

```
    cap staging deploy:setup
```

I get an error on the line :

```
   after "deploy:update", "deploy:cleanup"
```

default deployment tasks should be all loads ( update , cleanup,..)  ?

Here is my **deploy.rb** file

```
    # config valid only for current version of Capistrano
lock '3.4.0'

set :application, 'cockpit-api'
set :scm, :git

set :repository, 'git@gitlab.com:user/myapp.git'
set :branch, "master"
set :deploy_to, '/var/www/myapp'
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache

set :copy_strategy, :checkout
set :keep_releases, 5

set :use_sudo, false
set :copy_compression, :bz2
set :normalize_asset_timestamps, false

set :document_root, "/var/www/myapp"

set :ssh_options, {:forward_agent => true}
set :user, "deploy"
```

namespace :deploy do

```
task :start do 
  on primary roles :app do
   run "sudo restart #{application} || sudo start #{application}"
  end
end

task :stop do
  on primary roles :app do
    run "sudo stop #{application}"
  end
end

task :restart do
  on primary roles :app do
    start
  end
end

task :npm_install  do
  on primary roles :app do
    run "cd #{release_path} && npm install"
  end
end
```

end

after "deploy:update", "deploy:cleanup"
  after "deploy:update_code", "deploy:npm_install"

and my **staging.r**b

```
set :stage, :staging
server 'myapp.mydomain.com', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{app}
role :app, "deploy@myapp.mydomain.com"
```

my **Capfile** is quite minimum

```
# Load DSL and set up stages
require 'capistrano/setup'

# Include default deployment tasks
require 'capistrano/deploy'

# Load custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks` if you have any defined
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
```

Comment: I'm not clear, what's the error?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how Node.js is typically deployed via Capistrano 3, but there are many things wrong here. For example, there is no such thing in Capistrano 3 as `deploy:update`, nor is there `deploy:update_code`. Furthermore, Capistrano 3 doesn't have settings called `:copy_strategy` or `:copy_compression`.

My guess is that you followed documentation or an example that was written for Capistrano 2 and tried to add it into a Capistrano 3 project. Unfortunately that won't work, because Capistrano 2 and 3 are completely different and incompatible.

I suggest searching for an up to date example of Node.js + Capistrano that explicitly mentions Capistrano 3.

Comment: Thanks Matt ... I have now set a Capistrano 3 deploy, removing deprecated settings and updating after hooks...  nothing actually specific to node.js deployment,excepted a task for installing node modules into the shared folder, and starting the upstart job ( if used, like myself)